# Comparing NSDate by only the time component with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nspredicate

I'm familiar with using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to compare only certain components of `NSDate`.  However, I was wondering if it was possible to achieve this using `NSPredicate`, when filtering an array of dates or when fetching Core Data entities that have dates as one of the attributes.

For example, say I'm storing a Core Data entity `Person` with the attribute `birthday`.  `birthday` is an NSDate that stores both the date AND time of the person's birthday.  Can I use `NSPredicate` (or anything else) to fetch ONLY `Person`s with `birthday`s after 7 PM?

Or do I HAVE to store the date and time separately to achieve this? (Say, storing `birthdayDate` and `birthdayTime`.)

(I've tried filtering with an `NSDate` that only has a time component, and it seems like all `NSDate`s missing date components are considered EARLIER than `NSDates` that have both date and time components.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSPredicate has a `+predicateWithBlock:` that allows you to create custom predicates with arbitrary logic. However, you can't use predicates created this way as the predicate for a CoreData fetch from an SQLLite store. In that case, you'd perform a generic fetch, then filter the results with `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I had in mind.  I may still end up deciding to store the dates and time separately, but I think this a better answer in terms of the question.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's Core Data.  You have to denormalize out the time.

Comment: I'm still fairly new at coding... So, "denormalize" means store the time separately? Haha :P  Also, what if I already have an array of `Person`s (as opposed to fetching the entities through Core Data)?

Comment: You should be able to iterate through the array of Persons to find the the ones that qualify.  You can use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` for that.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Just a final question... In general, storing the time separately and letting Core Data handle things would be better performance-wise, right?